# Solve the differential equation. $yx^3y'=\sqrt{1+y^2}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Solve the differential equation. $$yx^3y'=\sqrt{1+y^2}$$

I tried to use this replacement here:
$$y=tx$$ $$y'=t+t'x$$

But then it turns out some garbage. Help me with this problem, please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint,
$$\dfrac{dy^2}{\sqrt{1+y^2}}=\dfrac{2}{x^3}dx$$
then $y^2=u$

Answer (score 2):

Hint: $\frac{y dy}{\sqrt{1+y^2}} = \frac {dx}{x^3}$

Now substitute $\sqrt{1+y^2}$ by $t$ and solve.

**EDIT:**

$\sqrt{1+y^2} =t \implies 1+y^2 = t^2 \implies 2ydy = 2tdt \implies y dy = t dt$

Therefore, $\frac{tdt}{t} = \frac {dx}{x^3} \implies dt = \frac {dx}{x^3}$

Integrating both sides we get, $t=\frac{x^{-2}}{-2} +c \implies \sqrt{1+y^2}= \frac{-1}{2x^2}+c$

Comment: No need to substitute anything, this would only make things more complicated. It is enough to note that $(1+y^2)' = y y'$.

Comment: @AlexM. I don't think it turned out to be complicated...